# Missing TextSpan's onTap callback using SelectableText (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I need 1) in some text (chapter) every word to receive taps (to implement words highlighting) while not losing 2) native text selection (for copy).

I achieved only 1) using RichText and only 2) using SelectableText but never together. SelectableText seems to be not passing on the events.

Every word must be a separate TextSpan (same spans with registered recognizer used for both Text and SelectableText):

```
List<TextSpan> spans = [];
for(String word in chapterText) {
  spans.add(TextSpan(
    text:word,
    recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => print('Tap from $word'),
  )
);
```

### Using RichText

OnTap event works for each TextSpan (so recognizer is set up properly).

```
Container(
  child: RichText(text: TextSpan(children: spans)),
),
```

### Using SelectableText

Copy-selection works, but TapGestureRecognizer on each TextSpan stops working.

```
Container(
  child: SelectableText.rich(
    TextSpan(children: spans),
//  onTap: () => print("Common onTap event"),
  ),
),
```

I acknowledge that double-tap and long-press events are already in use by native selection tool (at least on iOS). SelectableText.rich has its own onTap event (commented out), which probably is not passing the event on to underlying TextSpans.

In documentation [GestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan/recognizer.html) talks only about RichText, not SelectableText (which was added later).

Is this intended behaviour and are there workarounds?
Any hints are appreciated.

PS. Using Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6) and Xcode 11.0 and iOS Simulator 11.0.

Comment: Wondering if you have found an answer for this. I am having the same problem. You can add onTap event to SelectableText.Rich( onTap: (){}) that should work as well as the selection, however my problem is I am displaying several children spans and I need to have the opTap event on the children. The only other solution I see is to display multiple Selecteable.Rich() instead of multiple spans.

Comment: I gave up selectability for now -> using RichText